# How AWS S3 requests are made/calculated?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku, python-requests

I am new to AWS.
 I have created a S3 bucket a few days ago and I have noticed the number of requests made to it is already very high. Over the free tier limit for Put... I don't understand what is going on. I did connect a django heroku hosted app to the bucket but I am the only one having access to it and I only made a dozens of requests in the past few days.
Can you please help me understand what is going on, is this normal behaviour?

I didn't find my answer on Amazon forum and to access the technical support I need to upgrade my plan...

[image]

Thank you

Comment: **Side-note:** Don't get too hung-up on going beyond the Free Tier. Put requests to S3 are charged at `$0.005 per 1000 requests`, so it's potentially only going to cost you 3c. Your time is probably worth more than that.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your bucket is public. It is possible that if correct restrictions are not set then anyone can modify bucket.

Another thing to check is cloudtrail logs. It will show you the config changes (if any) on your S3 Bucket.

Also check if new files are added in the bucket. If yes, then maybe it's already compromised.

Comment: Thank you. It is not public and I don't see any unusual file activity. I have just created a cloudtrail log. I'll keep monitoring and see what happens.